# How do i make my flexbox flexible at any height of page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My problem is it doesn't fit some height size of the page, while I am dragged to a smaller size of the window. I want to fit in any height of the page. what's wrong in my code? what do I need to fit the height of page at any windows browser size?

```css
#features {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
 justify-content: center;  
}

#features .box {
 width:50%;
 margin:auto;
 max-height: 100%;
 padding: 2.5em;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="features">
  <div class="box box-light">
   <i class = 'fas fa-hotel fa-3x'></i>
   <h2> Great Location </h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, necessitatibus.</p> 
  </div>

  <div class="box box-primary">
   <i class = 'fas fa-utensils fa-3x'></i>
   <h2> Free Meals </h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, quibusdam. </p>
  </div>

  <div class="box box-light">
   <i class = 'fas fa-dumbbell fa-3x'></i>
   <h2> Fitness Room </h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, mollitia.</p>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: How do I make my flexbox flexible any height of the page.(question correction)

Comment: You can edit the question and correct the title.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `vh` unit.This unit is based on page height.
It's also a good idea to use `flex-wrap:wrap` to create breakpoints.

try this code :

```css
#features {
 display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
 flex-direction:row;
 align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
 justify-content: center;  
}

#features .box {
 width:50%;
 margin:auto;
 height: 100vh;
 padding: 2.5em;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="features">
  <div class="box box-light">
   <i class = 'fas fa-hotel fa-3x'></i>
   <h2> Great Location </h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, necessitatibus.</p> 
  </div>

  <div class="box box-primary">
   <i class = 'fas fa-utensils fa-3x'></i>
   <h2> Free Meals </h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, quibusdam. </p>
  </div>

  <div class="box box-light">
   <i class = 'fas fa-dumbbell fa-3x'></i>
   <h2> Fitness Room </h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, mollitia.</p>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Really? Can you take a picture

Comment: I just want to autofit in height and width in their 50% ration on screen. Not so much that unnecessary breakpoints. that's why it's not expected, sir!